# How to Reduce Stopping and Starting Time of Media Recorder in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am developing an application, the use case which I want to implement is as follow

- Application has an ongoing video recording process
- App Need to send some periodic logs with images to server, so whenever it send log

  1. It stops media recorder instance
  2. Remove surfaceView from recorder
  3. Attach Surface View with Camera
  4. Take Picture
  5. Start Media Recorder Again

Above mentioned process takes about 8 seconds, which is probably too much. Can someone guide me how I can reduce this 8 seconds?

In order to avoid any state conflict, I am using all this process in synchronize block.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey.. found any solution?

Comment: @PM25793 I tried almost all solutions, but as it was primarily dependent on  hardware latency, so unable to solve it. Then I implemented using onPreviewFrame method. Instead of stopping media recorder, I pick frame from running video preview